# Printing element width in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I'm trying to retrieve a html element width in javascript. Nothing appears on screen(plain text works, so I suppose there's something wrong with syntax). What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = $("#menu").width();
    document.write(width);
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Example </h1>

<ul id = "menu">
    <li><img src="img/Logo.jpg"/></li>
    <li><a href ="#">Home</a>
        <ul class = "sub1">
            <li><a href ="#">News</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href ="#">Machines</a>
        <ul class = "sub1">
            <li><a href ="#">Type1</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#">Type2</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#">Type3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href ="#">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href ="#">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>

<div id "main">
    <h2> Whatever </h2>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're computing and printing the width when the element doesn't yet exist.

You can do this :

```
<div id=head></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){ // called when the DOM is ready
          var width = $("#menu").width();
          $('#head').html(width);
     });
</script>
```

As you saw, I used a `div` instead of `head`, because setting the content of the `head` to the width doesn't make sense. If you want to change the title of the page, use

```
document.title = width;
```

As was noticed by j08691, you use jQuery but you don't seem to import it. If the code you show is your real header, then you need to add something like this in your `head` element :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Might want to note that this requires jQuery.

Comment: I think j08691 means to include the jQuery library as it is not included in the OP's example.